Trying to start tomcat 9 and receiving org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException
Im using [Apache Tomcat/9.0.96] and JDK 1.8_421
When I startup TOMCAT I'm receiving this error
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/gol] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2235)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2165)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.scanWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4352)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    ... 27 more

dez 02, 2024 5:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/gol] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2235)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2165)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.scanWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4352)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    ... 27 more

dez 02, 2024 5:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: O componente Server requerido falhou ao iniciar, por isso, o Tomcat não pode iniciar
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gol]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/gol] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2235)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:2165)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.scanWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4352)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    ... 27 more

I guess this caused by bouncy castle lib but I cant remove then and cant update too cause is working at prod with no problem and has always worked before formatting my pc.
someone can help me?

You might have a cyclic dependency but if you are sure that the exact setup is running in Prod I suggest you to run with an higher stack size.
For example by passing -Xss2m as additional java option Add JVM options in Tomcat
